# Why is friction only on the back wheel?

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

[image]

This is how I understand friction when a bicycle is moving uphill. On the backwheels there will be friction in the forward direction to oppose the rotation of the wheel. But at the front wheel we are pushing it forward with the back wheel --> Friction is in the opposite direction to make it move forward.

Am I right ?
This is a free body diagram of a bicycle with constant speed!
Why is there only one friction force in the free body diagram? It is like that on all of my exam questions....

Comment: How is the motion of this bike rider? Is he accelerating? I constant speed?

Comment: Constant speed @steeven

Comment: What's keeping the bicycle from rolling downhill towards the left? Not the front wheel: It is free-spinning. Only the rear wheel is resisting against the bicycle rolling back down the hill. Now if the problem instead stated that the bicyclist had stopped pedaling and was resting with no force on the pedals, and was holding the bike in position by applying the front wheel brakes, then the situation would be reversed: The friction vector F(A) would then be  associated with the front wheel.

Answer (score 2):

If the rider is not accelerating, there is no need for any force to do torque on the front wheel. Only gravity, normal force and the bike steering pole put forces on the front wheel, and non of them cause torques (all act in the middle).

Static friction is a force that only exists **when needed**! So when no other torques need to be balanced, no static friction appears. The front wheel just rolls effortless, without being stopped and without being helped.

On the rear wheel on the other hand, the rider pushes the pedals and creates a torque. Static friction appears to balance this, so the wheel doesn't slide.

Comment: What do you mean when you say all act in the middle? @Steeven

Comment: @Krister The steering pole gives a force to the wheel centre. The normal force is directed through the wheel centre. Gravity can be averaged into one weight force pulling in the centre-of-mass, which here is the wheel centre